# Find consesutive lines in a string starting with "pipe"

Tags: c#, regex

I'm quite new to regular expressions and searched and tried for some hours to find a solution for the following problem.

I have a string like this:

```
|Text1|Text2|Text3\n|Text4|Text5|Text6\nSomething else\n|Text6|Text8|Text9\n
```

There are several "lines" of text (where lines means newline-characters), some of them starting with a `|` (and maybe including other pipes).

I need a Regular Expression for C#'s `RegEx` which delivers the following groups:

Group1:

```
|Text1|Text2|Text3\n|Text4|Text5|Text6\n
```

Group2:

```
|Text6|Text8|Text9\n
```

In other words: For every line starting with a `|` I need the whole line. If there are several consecutive lines all starting with a `|`, I need those lines together in one group.

As requested here some additional examples:

**Example 1**

The follwing input

```
Text1|Text2\n
```

should return no match, as there is no line starting with a `|`

**Example 2**

The follwing input

```
|Text1|Text2
```

should return no match, as there is no line ending with `\n`

**Example 3**

The follwing input

```
sometext\n|Text1|Text2\nsometext
```

should return 1 group

```
|Text1|Text2\n
```

because the line starts with a `|` and ends with a `\n`

**Example 4**

The follwing input

```
sometext\n|someothertext\nsometext\n|someothertext\n
```

should return 2 groups

```
|someothertext\n
```

and

```
|someothertext\n
```

because these two lines start with a `|` and end with a `\n`

**Example 5**

The follwing input

```
sometext\n|someothertext\n|sometext\n|someothertext\n
```

should return 1 group

```
|someothertext\n|sometext\n|someothertext\n
```

because the three lines all start with a `|` and end with a `\n` and they are consecutive.

I found the following RegEx to match one line starting with `|` and end with a `\n`:

```
(?s)(\\n\|)((.*?)\\n)
```

but it doesn't recognize consecutive lines. I know i somehow need to use a backreference `\1`, but i didn't get it working yet.

**To clarify**: my actual task is to enhance 
the following Markdown for WPF-library https://github.com/theunrepentantgeek/Markdown.XAML so that it supports table-syntax.

As the markdown for WPF-library is based on a set of RegEx expressions used in an IEnumerable-pipe, I wanted to stay in that pattern and just add the part needed for tables.

A table in markdown is described by several lines starting with a pipe, where each column of the table is separated by a pipe. Consecutive lines starting with a pipe belong to one table. The content of each "column" (which is the value between two pipes in a line), can be any text or even another markdown-expression.

The table-syntax for markdown is described here https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables.

Comment: Interesting problem, though your example is obscure . . . for instance it isn't clear to me if Test6 was deliberately a repeat or not.  As is stated above, some specific examples would be helpful.  This problem would be a challenge even for a RegEx pro because "|" is also a RegEx operator and will need to be quoted each time you use it PLUS because of the new lines you'll need special options so that RegEx will treat the whole thing as one input.  It is a tough first problem.  More below.

Comment: For a problem like this I strongly recommend a RegEx Tester . . . be sure to select one that does specifically C#.  After a Quick Google I found this one: http://regexstorm.net/tester  I am not saying this particular one is good or bad, but only that it is one I found easily.  Doing your problem in a tester like this will make it much easier to run though examples quickly.  You'll learn a lot about how RegEx works as you watch it work as well.  Hint One: back quote all your pipe symbols.  Hint Two: I am pretty sure you'll need the "Multi-Line" option, but I leave it to you to read the docs.

Comment: Hi Andreas, the context you've added about what feature you're trying to add is largely irrelevant. Including examples of what your code is and what regex+code solutions you have tried so far will help narrow down your question and make it more answerable.

Comment: What you are attempting though, is not a good fit for a pure-regex solution. @AleksAndreev is correct that a code+regex solution would probably be a better fit. For example, using a regex that matches one table row and using it a code loop to move through the input until the next bit of data is not a new row for the current table you are parsing.

Comment: Hi Will, i don't think that the context is irrelevant. @AleksAndreev stated that a regular expression is not always a good fit for regular expression and so did you (and i agree), so i added the explanantion that the library is want to extend is based on regular expressions and i wanted to stick with that pattern. Frank found my example obscure, so i pointed to what feature i want to implement to give more context.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not need RegEx at all. Just split your input by "\n" and then group your lines in smart way. Try this code:

```
var input = "|Text1|Text2|Text3\n|Text4|Text5|Text6\nSomething else\n|Text6|Text8|Text9\n";

var lines = input.Split(new[] {'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .GroupAdjacent(line => line.StartsWith("|"))
    .Where(x => x.Key) // select only lines that starts with pipe
    .Select(g => string.Join("\n", g))
    .ToArray();
```

It use [`GroupAdjacent`](https://morelinq.github.io/2.1/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_GroupAdjacent__2.htm) method from `MoreLinq` library

For your input output will be

[image]